# I am Trying to to do Oauth with twitter in python using flask and getting request page is invalid

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, oauth, google-cloud-platform, flash-message

I am getting the following error

```
Whoa there!
The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake
```

1) The following method in which we are calling the twitter  credentials to your Api

2)The callback function is static

3) i am using Oauth 1  and using google cloud for hosting

4)I have already   cleared the cache 2 times still no use

```
.def _twitter(self):
        # Get the access token supplied
        oauth_token = self.test_credentials.get('oauth_token')
        oauth_token_secret = self.test_credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')
        if not oauth_token or not oauth_token_secret:
            raise AuthenticationException('Invalid request format.', 400)

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(current_app.config['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'], current_app.config['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'])
        auth.set_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        user = api.verify_credentials()

        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationException('Unable to verify credentials with remote server.', 500)

        # Save the user
        auth_string = self._auth_string(unicode(user.id_str))

        stored_user = User.query(User.auth_ids == auth_string).get()

        if not stored_user:
            return User(name=user.name)

        if stored_user and not stored_user.name:
            stored_user.name = user.name
            stored_user.put()

        return stored_user
```

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this message? This looks like the OAuth flow is failing outside the method in the OP

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add my  callback function in the twitter api callbacks (these resolved my error)